# How can i set a border for this table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
</head>    
<body>
    <script>
        var num = 2;
        for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            document.write(num + " * " + i + " = " + num * i);
            document.write('<br>');
        }
    </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

O/P:

```
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
2 * 5 = 10
2 * 6 = 12
2 * 7 = 14
2 * 8 = 16
2 * 9 = 18
2 * 10 = 20
```

This is a javascript code in which i printed 2-Table.But i need to place a border around that table..Seeking for an help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply wrap the JavaScript generated content in a block level element (`pre` for example) and then use CSS to display a border.

Note that I rewrote the `<br>` line so that the trailing line break is omitted after the last row, optional and for demo only.

```css
pre {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<script>
  var num = 2;
  for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    if (i !== 1) {document.write('<br>')};
    document.write(num + " * " + i + " = " + num * i);
  }
</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: Sir i'm Trying To Display The Output Using Functions...Is This The Right Way! <body>
    <div onload="myFunction()"></div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var num = 2;
            for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                document.write(num + " * " + i + " = " + num * i);
                document.write('<br>');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

To adapt on the code you already have, here's a quick solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/0dmvs3pz/

```
<script>
    document.write('<table border="1">');
    var num = 2;
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

        document.write('<tr>');

        document.write('<td>'+ 2 + '</td>');

        document.write('<td>'+ '*' + '</td>');

        document.write('<td>'+ i + '</td>');

        document.write('<td>'+ '=' + '</td>');

        document.write('<td>'+ (2*i) + '</td>');                               

        document.write('</tr>');
    }
    document.write('</table>');
</script>
```

Though this is a pretty messy way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements have property `style` that represents object with element's styles. If you modify it — you'll change style of your element.

```
   elem.style.border = "1px solid #red"
                // the same as
                elem.style.borderWidth = "1px";
                elem.style.borderColor = "#red";
                elem.style.borderStyle = "solid";
```

Using **borderTop**, **borderRight**, **borderBottom**, **borderLeft** properties you can change only borders what you need.